# Neofetch autostart in Awesome WM not working

Tags: window-manager, gnome-terminal, awesome-wm, autostart

Trying to run Neofetch in Linux automatically on startup in Awesome WM.

Problem is the terminal opens and closes, doesn't stay open.

If I change the gnome-terminal option to stay open, I get errors.

I'm using:

`gnome-terminal -- neofetch`

There is a deprecated -e option, it works with other things but behaves the same in that the terminal doesn't stay open when running neofetch.

Other terminal commands are working and terminals remain open, just neofetch closes expectantly

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because the command finishes and exit. Depending on what you want, you can use `less -r`, `watch` or `bash -c 'neofetch && bash'` to get around this.

- **less**: allow you to scroll and search, which isn't very useful
- **watch**: Refresh the content of `neofetch` every few seconds (set the rate to a very high value)
- **bash** (or **zsh**): Drop you to a terminal after `neofetch` has finished

Comment: Thank you so much...  

It worked in an autorun script called by the rc.lua config file using your bash method..

Thanks again..........................